# PHP Convert Text File to Array and Merge with another Array

Tags: php, arrays, text-files, unique

I have a main.txt file that contains the following:

```
new featuredProduct('', '25844'), 
new featuredProduct('', '19800'), 
new featuredProduct('', '23869'), 
new featuredProduct('', '23903'), 
new featuredProduct('', '14573'), 
new featuredProduct('', '7949'), 
new featuredProduct('', '13815'), 
new featuredProduct('', '27042'), 
new featuredProduct('', '24383'),
```

I also have trim.txt file that contains the following:

```
14573
23903
19800
```

I am attempting to convert trim into the same format as main, combine both as one array, then filter out the duplicates with array_unique.

**What I've Tried:**

```
$main = array_unique(file("main.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$trim = array_unique(file("trim.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));

//formats trim to the same as main

foreach ($trim as $m) {
    $m = "new featuredProduct('', ". "'". urlencode(trim($m)) ."')" . "," . "\n<br />";
    echo $m;
}

//merge into one array
$t = (array) $m;
$res = array_unique(array_merge($t, $main));

foreach ($res as $re) {
echo $re . "<br>";
}
```

**My Result:**

I am getting the following output:

```
new featuredProduct('', '25844'), 
new featuredProduct('', '23903'), 
new featuredProduct('', '19800'), 

new featuredProduct('', '25844'), 
new featuredProduct('', '19800'), 
new featuredProduct('', '23869'), 
new featuredProduct('', '23903'), 
new featuredProduct('', '14573'), 
new featuredProduct('', '7949'), 
new featuredProduct('', '13815'), 
new featuredProduct('', '27042'), 
new featuredProduct('', '24383'),
```

So as you can see both arrays are getting displayed but they are not merging and displaying the unique values.

I think what's going wrong is that as soon as I loop over $trim and assign to $m, it's no longer an array.  I have tried to assign $m to an array $t ..

```
$t = (array) $m;
```

then passed $t to the array_merge function, but this is not working.

So my question is how can I make $m an array that works and can be passed to the array_merge() therefore allowing me to display just unique values in the merged array?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you need to store the code around the number? It seems more logical to me to separate the data from the code and just store the numbers. Then you can use them however and wherever you need them.

Comment: Take the `echo` out of your first `foreach` loop

Comment: First append $m to the last $m and then you can split with "\n" the variable $m with `split("\n", $m);` after for. It will return an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues, among them: Don't add `\n<br />` to `$trim` that makes it different and not unique. Also, `$m` will only be the last one in the loop.

Make sure to use the `&` for `$m` in the loop to change the actual array:

```
$main = file("main.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$trim = file("trim.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);

foreach ($trim as &$m) {
    $m = "new featuredProduct('', '" . urlencode(trim($m)) . "'),";
}
$res = array_unique(array_merge($trim, $main));
```

Comment: You were right AbraCadaver.  My mistake was additional \n<br> and trying to assign $m to another variable instead of using &$m.  Thank kindly for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply append the new items to the exisitng `$main` array, then call `array_unique` on it:

```
$main = array_unique(file("main.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
$trim = array_unique(file("trim.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));

foreach ($trim as $m) {
    $main[] = sprintf("new featuredProduct('', '%s'),", $m);
}
$res = array_unique($main);

echo implode("<br>", $res);
```